# Echo class "active" if current url Magento

Tags: php, css, magento

I have several links in my Magento template file. If a user is currently viewing a page that is one of the links I would like that link to display the CSS class "active". How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$routeName   =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier  =  Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
```

The above variable `$routeName` can be used to check whether the current page is a CMS page. The other variable `$identifier` will output the page identifier.

Comment: @phant0m I aded the following code to my link an no identifier is being applied. `<a href="../../products/sippi-grip"<?php $routeName   =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier  =  Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>
>SippiGrip</a>`

Comment: @Sam: You are only defining variables, not actually outputting anything to the page.

Comment: @phant0m In regards to my original post. How would can I make it output a class I can style for active links?

Comment: $routeName   =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier  =  Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
<a href="../../products/sippi-grip/<?php echo $identifier;?>" class="active">SippiGrip</a>
Check if this works. You can always change the style name active as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that contains all the links (or pages)

```
$urls = array('home.php', 'about.php', 'contact.php');
```

Then compare the current url with the one in the array:

```
<li><a href="about.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $urls))
 { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>About Us</a></li>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento assigns classes to each page individually
The easiest way to get active states was to to assign each link a class and then write a CSS role for the specific body class and link class.

```
     body.page-a a.class-a {
    color:red}
     body.page-b a.class-b {
    color:red}

    <body class="page-b">
    <a class="class-a">page a</a>
    <a class="class-b">page b</a>
</body>
```